# Uploading files using html5 FormData in dojo(without using XmlHttpRequest)

Tags: dojo

I want to upload files using FormData Object(html5) in dojo and without using XmpHttpRequest.
I am using dojo.xhrPost to upload files.

Please post your ideas/thoughts and experience.

Thanks
Mathirajan S

Comment: I'm confused. `XMLHttpRequest` is the base of all AJAX requests, even for `dojo.xhrPost`. What do you think the **xhr** in xhrPost stands for? (**X** ML **H** ttp **R** equest). So in fact you're using `XMLHttpRequest` too.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But my question is, Can I use FormData object to upload files with dojo.xhrPost.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I am assuming you *do* want to use XHR (which would make sense given that FormData is part of the XHR2 spec).

`dojo/request/xhr` (introduced in Dojo 1.8) supports passing a `FormData` object via the `data` property of the options object, so that may get you what you want.

```
request.post(url, {
    data: formdataObjectHere
    // and potentially other options...
}).then(...);
```

The legacy `dojo/_base/xhr` module does not explicitly support XHR2, but it does lean on `dojo/request/xhr` now, so it might end up working anyway, but no guarantees there.

More information on `dojo/request/xhr` can be found in [the Reference Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html).